# How can I get desktop notifications on irssi?

Tags: notification, irssi

I'm using irssi on Gnome 3, but I do use KDE 4 sometimes. I like irssi very much but I miss any notification feature. I don't use irssi over ssh.

Comment: weechat has a plugin for this as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There seems to be a couple kicking about:

https://github.com/stickster/irssi-libnotify (previously at http://code.google.com/p/irssi-libnotify/)

or..

http://wahjava.wordpress.com/2008/06/15/irssi-notifications/

They're just Perl scripts you drop into `~/.irssi/scripts` so you could tweak them to suit you.

Comment: thanks a lot. I had to edit the notify.pl to make the notifications transient (otherwise they fill up the notification area). Adding --hint=int:transient:1 did it.

Answer (score 4):

http://code.google.com/p/irssi-libnotify/ works great for me.

If you want it to notify all messages instead of just hilighted ones remove  `|| !($dest->{level} & MSGLEVEL_HILIGHT)` from the script.